# dlib not installing (cmake)

Tags: python, cmake, dlib

Hi I am trying to install dlib via cmake but I keep getting **error: legacy-install-failure** here is the full readout ***(I have replaced my actual user name with USER)***

```
>C:\Users\USER->pip install dlib
Collecting dlib
  Using cached dlib-19.23.1.tar.gz (7.4 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for dlib, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: dlib
  Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  × Running setup.py install for dlib did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [73 lines of output]
      running install
      C:\Users\USER-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      package init file 'tools\python\dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      running build_ext
      C:\Users\USER-\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-q7gocxf3\dlib_ba1eccb06b884bc4a89365e82ab2b34f\setup.py:129: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
        if LooseVersion(cmake_version) < '3.1.0':
      Building extension for Python 3.10.4 (tags/v3.10.4:9d38120, Mar 23 2022, 23:13:41) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
      Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\USER-\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-q7gocxf3\dlib_ba1eccb06b884bc4a89365e82ab2b34f\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\USER-\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-q7gocxf3\dlib_ba1eccb06b884bc4a89365e82ab2b34f\build\lib.win-amd64-3.10 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\Users\USER-\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\USER-\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-q7gocxf3\dlib_ba1eccb06b884bc4a89365e82ab2b34f\build\lib.win-amd64-3.10 -A x64'
      -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
      CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (message):
        !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        You must use Visual Studio to build a python extension on windows.  If you
        are getting this error it means you have not installed Visual C++.  Note
        that there are many flavors of Visual Studio, like Visual Studio for C#
        development.  You need to install Visual Studio for C++.
        !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
      -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\USER-\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-q7gocxf3\dlib_ba1eccb06b884bc4a89365e82ab2b34f\setup.py", line 222, in <module>
          setup(
        File "C:\Users\USER-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 79, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "C:\Users\USER-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
        File "C:\Users\USER-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 163, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "C:\Users\USER-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 967, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "C:\Users\USER-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1196, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\USER-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\USER-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 68, in run
          return orig.install.run(self)
        File "C:\Users\USER-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\install.py", line 670, in run
          self.run_command('build')
        File "C:\Users\USER-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\USER-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1196, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\USER-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\USER-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "C:\Users\USER-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\USER-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1196, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\USER-\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\USER-\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-q7gocxf3\dlib_ba1eccb06b884bc4a89365e82ab2b34f\setup.py", line 134, in run
          self.build_extension(ext)
        File "C:\Users\USER-\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-q7gocxf3\dlib_ba1eccb06b884bc4a89365e82ab2b34f\setup.py", line 171, in build_extension
          subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
        File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 369, in check_call
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\USER-\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-q7gocxf3\\dlib_ba1eccb06b884bc4a89365e82ab2b34f\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\USER-\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-q7gocxf3\\dlib_ba1eccb06b884bc4a89365e82ab2b34f\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.10', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\\Users\\USER-\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\USER-\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-q7gocxf3\\dlib_ba1eccb06b884bc4a89365e82ab2b34f\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.10', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      [end of output]
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure
× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> dlib
note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Comment: Seems like there's a good explanation buried inside that output. It literally tells you `You need to install Visual Studio for C++.` You may also try to install the `wheel` package first because it says `Using legacy 'setup.py install' for dlib, since package 'wheel' is not installed.`

Answer (score 1):

download cmake executable file on your pc, install it and install cmake build tools for c++ from visual studio build tools. After installing cmake with visual studio build tools, you need to download dlib wheel file from this github repo: https://github.com/Tobyyosoba777/Computer-Vision-OpenCv-Python-/tree/main/Libraries

download:
dlib-19.22.99-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl

and download:
dlib-19.22.99.win-amd64-py3.9.exe

install the .exe file on your pc, restart it(not necessary) and open the current directory of the downloaded .whl file where it is saved on your pc in your python/anaconda terminal/ cmd

for example:

> C:\Users\USER->cd desktop
> "if you downloaded the file to your desktop"
> this command will move you to the current directory of the .whl file

then input:
"pip install dlib-19.22.99-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl"

that should work

Answer (score 0):

Dlib [documentation](http://dlib.net/compile.html) says:

> We should also make a special note of the problems associated with using precompiled C++ libraries with Visual Studio. The TLDR is that you should not use precompiled libraries (i.e. .lib files) with Visual Studio unless you really know what you are doing. This is not a dlib limitation. It has nothing to do with dlib. It's just how Visual Studio works. Please do not ask me about it. If you want to understand this you should read the Visual Studio documentation and this excellent overview in particular.

With that beeing said, it's likely they don't ship precompiled library with their installers, and it order to use it on windows you have to compile it yourself, and to compile it you need Visual Studio (mingw or clang wont work).

If you dont mind installing another instance of python in your system, you can use conda to get precompiled dlib.